# What does the comma mean in the graphoid axioms?

Tags: notation, conditional-probability

I have been trying to understand the graphoid axioms, one of which--Decomposition--claims that

$$ (X \bot Y,W |Z) \implies (X \bot Y|Z).$$

In Pearl's book *Causality*, he writes $\bot$ with two vertical lines, and omits the comma.  The list is just after equation 1.29 in that text.
Axiom C4 in [this lecture](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Esteffen/teaching/cimpa/intro.pdf) by Steffen Lauritzen, uses the comma. Wikipedia seems to claim that it is a logical and uses a [different notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphoid):

$$I(X,Z,Y)\ \text{ means that }\ (X \bot Y |Z).$$

There are several answers to questions like this, but as far as I can tell none of them actually **give a definition** of the comma.  Neither do any writings by Pearl or any other online sources I have read, except where they contradict each other.  I can't prove the statement if I can't tell what it is saying!

Now before you just say, "It's an and" or some such, I will point out that multiple people have claimed that it is a set intersection, a set union, a logical and--meaning that it isn't one statement but rather two to begin with? and I don't know what else. I tried my best guess and found a counterexample, so clearly I don't know what it is trying to say.

I want to know what is the *definition* of the claim.  Exactly.  No hand waving.  If you can carefully distinguish sets from random variables from probabilities that would also be a big help.

If I ever figure this out I promise to share my understanding as clearly as possible with others.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the axioms you're using? The wikipedia page on [graphoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphoid) lists an axiom called "decomposition", but it looks different from what you wrote here (at the very least, the notation is different).

Comment: I have added links and described the variations in notation.

Comment: The decomposition axiom is simply one of the axioms defining a particular kind of ternary relation called a graphoid, denoted here by $(X\perp Y\mid Z)$. There are various models of graphoids, and depending on the model, the entities $X,Y,Z$ can be sets of vertices of a graph, random variables, sets of random variables, and doubtless others that I’ve not encountered in a quick search. The interpretation of the comma is going to depend on the model; when $X,Y,Z$ are sets, it seems consistently to be union.

Comment: Except that it is interpreted as intersection elsewhere.  What you are describing is exactly what I am trying to learn!

Comment: I had an answer but I deleted it because I realized you were not talking about the comma in the Wikipedia notation $I(X,Z,Y)$, but in the notation $(X \bot Y,W |Z) \implies (X \bot Y|Z)$. That comma is a union of sets of random variables.  In Wikipedia, "Definitions" section, it is explicitly stated as a union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenation means *and* in Pearl's independence axioms.  So Pearl's Decomposition $(X\bot YW \;| Z)$ should be read as "$X$ is independent of $(Y\&W)$ given $Z$."

Pearl uses comma for *and* in probability statements.  This seems clear given (1.28)and (1.29), which are pretty standard defintions of conditional independence and regular probabilistic independence.

With this understanding, you can derive Decomposition from the definition of conditional independence in (1.28) [p. 11 in 2nd ed.].

Intersection (the set-theoretic operation, not the graph axiom) is the set-theoretic version of *and*.  They're equivalent because you can convert statements to sets in which they hold, and vice versa.

Comma is *and* in the probability statements in Wikipedia.  In $I(X,Y,Z)$ the commas distinguish arguments to the predicate $I$, which means "$X$ is independent of $Y$ given $Z$" as stated on the page.

Lauritzen seems to use comma for *and*, though I haven't checked carefully.  That looks right, though, and he uses $\cup$ (union, *or*) in other places.

Comment: If it is a logical "and" as you say, then the statement is completely tautological. "X is independent of Y and W given Z" then literally means "X is independent of Y given Z and X is independent of W given Z". The entire axiom simply becomes a definition of the comma with no actual content.

Comment: Yeah it's a simple theorem.

Comment: It's not even a theorem. It is literally nothing but a definition of the notation.

Comment: Call it what you want!  As Pearl says it's one of the "properties satisifed by the conditional independence relation".

Comment: Thank you.  It seems I wasted a great deal of time over absolutely nothing.

Comment: I know how that goes.  Different communities just take for granted that the meaning of a particular notation is obvious, and as an outsider, I sometimes have to struggle to figure out what's going on.  And someone who already knows the material but not the notation will see the parallels and figure it out right away.